# How to make a binary classification of panel data in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-analysis, panel-data

I start to study data analysis using R and came across panel data, on the basis of which it is necessary to conduct binary classification.

The data looks like this:

```
> head(data)
  PERIOD ID V_1 V_2 V_3
1      1  1  27   0   0
2      2  1  19   0  NA
3      3  1  22   0   0
4      1  2  NA  NA   0
5      2  2  28   0   0
6      3  2  27   0   0
```

The first thing that came to mind was to transform the panel data as follows:

```
> head(trns)
  ID 1_V_1 1_V_2 1_V_3 2_V_1 2_V_2 2_V_3 3_V_1 3_V_2 3_V_3
1  1    27     0     0    19     0    NA    22     0     0
2  2    NA    NA     0    28     0     0    27     0     0
3  3    26    18     3    26    19     5    28    23     2
4  4    28    30    NA    19    20     1    17    19     0
5  5    28     0     0    25     0     0    30     0     0
6  6    14     0    NA    19     0     3    14    NA     0
```

But unfortunately, this did not work. It seems to me that this is the wrong approach. Therefore, I turn to the community for advice.

How to work with such data?

UPD1:

`Period` - period number (consecutive periods, 1 is the oldest);

`ID` - the customer ID;

`V_1-V_3` - customer activity data over the period.

```
> str(train_target)
'data.frame':   3871 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ TARGET: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
```

`TARGET` - value of the target label (1 - belongs to the segment, 0 - does not belong to the segment).

UPD2:

I added [a link to the data](https://github.com/ship-it-hub/m).

In addition to `tabular_data` and `train_target` described above, the link also has hash values ​​for one categorical variable, which is also desirable to include in the model.

Comment: It depends what you want/need to do with the data. Why do you think it needs binary classification?

Comment: @4rj4n based on such (panel) data, I want to make  the binary classification. For example, there is information about some activity of the client for a certain time, and based on this information it is necessary to classify the client to one or the other group.

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood something, either in the data or method. When talking about binary classification we want to predict 0/1 outcomes. Eg. Did the firm default its loan? did a person die? It doesn't seem to me like you have such an outcome. Having such it still depends what you want with your days. What is V_1 - V_3? What is ID? What is period? You should likely read up on some basic econometrics or statistics, in order to properly answer how these should be treated in a model.

Comment: @Oliver thanks for the note. I added information